# Choose what to drop when .distinct()

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I am working on species distribution modelling based on observations and I would like to obtain distinct locations per species in my FeatureCollection. So far easy.

However, some of the observations are of low quality. I would thus like to be able to drop duplicates with e.g. `.distinct()` but in case of a duplicate, to choose which one to keep based on a boolean property.

Something like this:

```
high_quality_obs = tot_obs.filterMetadata('high_quality', 'equals', True).distinct('.geo')

low_quality_obs = tot_obs.filterMetadata('high_quality', 'equals', False).distinct('.geo')

tot_obs = high_quality_obs.merge(low_quality_obs).distinct()
```

But in the last `.distinct()` it should choose to keep the observations with `'high_quality' = True` if it is possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you provide a working example that indicates how your data looks like, e.g. dummy data or something similar? It will probably involve a 2 or 3 step approach like finding all high quality values, and from those get a list of distinct names that you can then apply to filter to original list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another useful possible way of solving the problem:

```
low_quality_obs = low_quality_obs.filter(ee.Filter.bounds(high_quality_obs).Not())
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think a couple ways to accomplish this but I am not super familiar with Earth Engine.

If you are only interested in observations from the low-quality tables if they don't have high-quality duplicate, then we just need to get distinct records from the high-quality tables and just ignore any low-quality observations if they have the same geometry.

```
high_quality_obs = tot_obs.filterMetadata('high_quality', 'equals', True).distinct('.geo') 
low_quality_obs = tot_obs.filterMetadata('high_quality', 'equals', False).distinct('.geo')

# This filter should return 'true' if the geometries match.
obs_filter = ee.Filter().intersects(leftField: '.geo', rightField: '.geo'))

# Apply the filter to a join and get the invert.
# Should return only low_quality_obs that didn't intersect high_quality_obs.
low_quality_obs_only = ee.Join().invert().apply(low_quality_obs, high_quality_obs, obs_filter)

# No need to call distinct because they should already be distinct at this point.
tot_obs = high_quality_obs.merge(low_quality_obs_only)
```

Otherwise, you could use a loop and hash table with the FeatureCollection.iterate() method to check if a feature with the same geometry has been seen and then if it is high-quality. Returning only features that are distinct with a bias for high-quality features.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The idea worked, but I had to change something small, see below